# How to map ataX.0 identifiers in kern.log error messages to actual /dev/sdY devices?

Tags: linux, sata

Consider following `kern.log` snippet:

```
 ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
 ata4.00: cmd 61/00:78:40:1e:6c/04:00:f0:00:00/40 tag 15 ncq 524288 out
        res 41/04:00:00:00:00/04:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x1 (device error)
 ata4.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
 ata4.00: error: { ABRT }
 ata4: hard resetting link
 ata4: nv: skipping hardreset on occupied port
 ata4: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
 ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
 ata4: EH complete
```

How can I identify which hard drive the kernel actually means when it talks about `ata4.00`?

How can I find the corresponding `/dev/sdY` device name?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can find the corresponding /dev/sdY device via traversing the `/sys` tree:

```
$ find /sys/devices | grep '/ata[0-9]\+/.*/block/s[^/]\+$' \
    | sed 's@^.\+/\(ata[0-9]\+\)/.\+/block/\(.\+\)$@\1 => /dev/\2@'
```

With a more efficient `/sys` traversal (cf. [lsata.sh](https://github.com/gsauthof/utility/blob/master/lsata.sh)):

```
$ echo /sys/class/ata_port/ata*/../../host*/target*/*/block/s* | tr ' ' '\n' \
    | awk -F/ '{printf("%s => /dev/%s\n", $5, $NF)}'
```

Example output from a 2 disk system:

```
ata1 => /dev/sda
ata2 => /dev/sdb
```

Then, for reliably identifying the actual hardware you need to map /dev/sdY to the serial number, e.g.:

```
$ ls /dev/disk/by-id -l | grep 'ata.*sd[a-zA-Z]$'
```

### lssci

The `lssci` utility can also be used to derive the mapping:

```
$ lsscsi | sed 's@^\[\([^:]\+\).\+\(/dev/.\+\)$@\1,\2@' \
    | awk -F, '{ printf("ata%d => %s\n", $1+1, $2) }'
```

Note that the relevant lsscsi enumeration starts from 0 while the ata enumeration starts from 0.

### Syslog

If nothing else works one can look at the syslog/journal to derive the mapping.

The `/dev/sdY` devices are created in the same order as the ataX identifiers are enumerated in the `kern.log` while ignoring non-disk devices (ATAPI) and not-connected links.

Thus, following command displays the mapping:

```
$ grep '^May 28 2'  /var/log/kern.log.0  | \
   grep 'ata[0-9]\+.[0-9][0-9]: ATA-' | \
   sed 's/^.*\] ata//' | \
   sort -n | sed 's/:.*//' | \
   awk ' { a="ata" $1; printf("%10s is /dev/sd%c\n", a, 96+NR); }'
ata1.00 is /dev/sda
ata3.00 is /dev/sdb
ata5.00 is /dev/sdc
ata7.00 is /dev/sdd
ata8.00 is /dev/sde
ata10.00 is /dev/sdf
```

(Note that ata4 is not displayed because the above log messages are from another system.)

I am using `/var/log/kern.log.0` and not `/var/log/kern.log` because the boot messages are already rotated. I grep for `May 28 2` because this was the last boot time and I want to ignore previous messages.

To verify the mapping you can do some checks via looking at the output of:

```
$ grep '^May 28 2'  /var/log/kern.log.0  | \
grep 'ata[0-9]\+.[0-9][0-9]: ATA-'
May 28 20:43:26 hn kernel: [    1.260488] ata1.00: ATA-7: SAMSUNG SV0802N, max UDMA/100
May 28 20:43:26 hn kernel: [    1.676400] ata5.00: ATA-5: ST380021A, 3.19, max UDMA/10
[..]
```

And you can compare this output with `hdparm` output, e.g.:

```
$ hdparm -i /dev/sda

/dev/sda:

Model=SAMSUNG SV0802N [..]
```

(using Kernel 2.6.32-31)

Comment: This is just awesome, thank you so much for this excellent reply...

Comment: @stuarte, you are welcome - btw, [cks](http://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/) has done a writeup about all [the different naming schemes of SATA devices on current Linux systems](http://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/linux/LinuxSATANames). Regarding ataX identifiers he writes: 'These names do not appear in sysfs at all as far as I can see'

Comment: Hmm. My problem with the verify operation of this is I typically have 8+ disks of the exact same model so manufacturer checks are not that valuable.

Comment: @drescherjm, I've updated my answer. The new method should be robust and thus eliminate any need for a vendor check.

Comment: I have what I think is an improved sysfs script; in particular it handles double-digit ata numbers (/ata[0-9]/ won't match ata10) and also finds sata devices not named sd* (e.g. sr0): for a in /sys/class/ata_port/ata*; do printf '%s\t%s\n' "$(basename "$a")" "$(find "$a/device/" -iname 'block' -exec ls {} \;)"; done

Comment: @Jason, I've updated my answer - the first 2 command lines should work on systems with more than 10 and more than 24 disks/devices.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my version, modified from above.  Since I don't know the exact date the system was booted (for testing this it was 27 days ago), and I don't know which kern.log contains the data I need (some may be `gzipped` on my system), I use `uptime` and `date` to calculate an approximate system boot date (to the day, anyway), then use `zgrep` to search through all available kern.log files.

I also slightly modified the second `grep` statement, since it will now also show an ATAPI CD/DVD drive as well as ATA-* drives.

It could still use refinement (i.e. if system uptime is greater than a year), but should work OK for now.

```
#!/bin/bash

uptime=$(uptime | awk -F' '  '{ print $3" "$4 }' | sed s/,//)
date=$(date -d "$uptime ago" | awk '{print $2" "$3 }')
zgrep "$date"  /var/log/kern.log*  | \
grep 'ata[0-9]\+.[0-9][0-9]: ATA'  | \
sed 's/^.*\] ata//' | \
sort -n | sed 's/:.*//' | \
awk ' { a="ata" $1; printf("%10s is /dev/sd%c\n", a, 96+NR); }'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just had this same problem and found a another solution which one might like.

The lsscsi tool lists SCSI devices (or hosts) and their attribute.

With lsscsi one gets the ata name and the device name.

Looks like this:

```
$ lsscsi --long
[0:0:1:0]    cd/dvd  MATSHITA DVD-ROM UJDA780  1.50  /dev/sr0
  state=running queue_depth=1 scsi_level=6 type=5 device_blocked=0 timeout=30
[2:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      WDC WD3000FYYZ-0 01.0  /dev/sda
  state=running queue_depth=1 scsi_level=6 type=0 device_blocked=0 timeout=30
[3:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      WDC WD1002FBYS-0 03.0  /dev/sdb
  state=running queue_depth=1 scsi_level=6 type=0 device_blocked=0 timeout=30
[4:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      WDC WD1002FBYS-0 03.0  /dev/sdc
  state=running queue_depth=1 scsi_level=6 type=0 device_blocked=0 timeout=30
[5:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      WDC WD1002FBYS-0 03.0  /dev/sdd
  state=running queue_depth=1 scsi_level=6 type=0 device_blocked=0 timeout=30
[6:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      WDC WD3000FYYZ-0 01.0  /dev/sde
  state=running queue_depth=1 scsi_level=6 type=0 device_blocked=0 timeout=30
[7:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      WDC WD1002FBYS-0 03.0  /dev/sdf
  state=running queue_depth=1 scsi_level=6 type=0 device_blocked=0 timeout=30
```

On Ubuntu one can install lsscsi simply with

```
$ sudo apt-get install lsscsi
```

Comment: hm, and how do the `ataX` map to what part in the `lsscsi` output?

Comment: @maxschlepzig The first number in the : quads is the same as the ataX with one important distinction; the output of lsscsi is 0-indexed and ataZ is 1-indexed; so [2:0:0:0] would be ata3 which is /dev/sda in the output that longsleep posted

Comment: @Jason, ok, here is a one-liner: `lsscsi | sed 's@^\[\([^:]\+\).\+\(/dev/.\+\)$@\1,\2@' | awk -F, '{ printf("ata%d => %s\n", $1+1, $2) }'`

Comment: @Jason, see also my updated answer for an alternative that directly accesses `/sys/devices` without `lsscsi`.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above answers worked for me, and the lsscsi approach actually yielded the wrong answer, due to discrepancies between SCSI bus numbers and ATA numbers.  On a 21-disk system, I had many syslog reports about problems with ATA18 (HSM violations).  Which disk was causing these errors?  Some were usb drives, which made things considerably more confusing.  I needed an accounting of how each and every SCSI drive is attached to the system, and I wrote the script below that yields tabular listings for all SCSI disks (/dev/s[dr]?) regardless of whether ATA or USB.

Then, with all disk drives fully accounted-for, I was surprised to see that my ATA errors had nothing to do with *any* of my disk drives.  I had been asking the wrong question, and I think others might easily fall into the same trap, which is why I mention it here.  I then used a second approach that identified the hardware that was generating the HSM violation messages, also detailed in the documentation appearing in the script below.

```
#!/bin/bash

## This script lists the ata and usb bus numbers, as well as the
## overall "host" numbers, of each scsi disk.  The same information
## appears formatted four ways, redundantly, for ease of lookup by (1)
## device lettername, (2) ata bus, (3) usb bus, or (4) overall "host"
## number.

#######################################################

## Q: What if you're looking for an ATA bus number, e.g. ata18, that
##    isn't listed by this script?

## (1) Well, it's probably not a SCSI disk, at least not one that's
##     operating.

## (2) Somewhere in /sys you can find a mapping from the ATA bus
##     number to some overall host number, such as host17.  For example,
##     if you're looking for ata18, you can use a find command...

##     find /sys -type l -exec bash -c 'link=`readlink "$0"`; if [[ "$link" =~ /ata18/ ]] ; then echo $link ; fi' {} \;

##     ...which, after some delay, might yield output something like this:

##    ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/0000:02:00.0/ata18/ata_port/ata18
##    ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/0000:02:00.0/ata18/host17/target17:0:0/17:0:0:0/scsi_generic/sg5
##    ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/0000:02:00.0/ata18/link18/dev18.0/ata_device/dev18.0
##    ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/0000:02:00.0/ata18/host17/scsi_host/host17
##    ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/0000:02:00.0/ata18/link18/ata_link/link18
##    ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/0000:02:00.0/ata18/host17/target17:0:0/17:0:0:0/bsg/17:0:0:0
##    ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/0000:02:00.0/ata18/host17/target17:0:0/17:0:0:0/scsi_device/17:0:0:0
##    ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/0000:02:00.0/ata18/host17/target17:0:0/17:0:0:0/scsi_generic/sg5
##    ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/0000:02:00.0/ata18/host17/target17:0:0/17:0:0:0/bsg/17:0:0:0
##    ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/0000:02:00.0/ata18/host17/target17:0:0/17:0:0:0
##    ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/0000:02:00.0/ata18/host17
##    ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/0000:02:00.0/ata18/host17/target17:0:0

##     Then you might notice the "/host17/" or "scsi_device/17:0:0:0"
##     in the above output lines, and look in the output of...

##     lshw

##     .. for "scsi17" or "17:0" or such, and discover, somewhere in it ...

##     ...
##        *-scsi:5
##           physical id: 8
##           logical name: scsi17
##           capabilities: emulated
##         *-processor UNCLAIMED
##              description: SCSI Processor
##              product: 91xx Config
##              vendor: Marvell
##              physical id: 0.0.0
##              bus info: scsi@17:0.0.0
##              version: 1.01
##              capabilities: removable
##              configuration: ansiversion=5
##     ...

## ...thus learning that ata18 corresponds to an unclaimed device (but
## not actually a disk).  Q.E.D.

## P.S. the lsscsi command yields the following, which might lead
## one to think that the problem was being caused by a CD-ROM drive
## (SCSI18:0) rather than emanating from the Marvell (SCSI17:0):

## [17:0:0:0]   process Marvell  91xx Config      1.01  -        
## [18:0:0:0]   cd/dvd  HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GH22NS90  HN00  /dev/sr0 

## ... but ATA != SCSI, and 17 != 18.  The CD/DVD drive was ATA19, 
## actually.  You can still use lsscsi, but
## bear in mind that what you're seeing in the left column
## is *not* ATA numbers but rather SCSI bus numbers, and the two
## are not to be confused.
#######################################################

blockDevsDir=/sys/dev/block

declare -A scsiDevLetters
declare -A hostNumbers
declare -A ataNumbers
declare -A usbNumbers

scsiDevLetterRE='/s(d[a-z]|r[0-9])$'
hostNumberRE='/host([0-9]+)/'
ataNumberRE='/ata([0-9]+)/'
usbNumberRE='/usb([0-9]+)/'

cd "$blockDevsDir"
for busid in `ls -1` ; do
    linkval=`readlink "$busid" `
    if [[ "$linkval" =~ $scsiDevLetterRE ]] ; then
        scsiDevLetter="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        if [[ "$linkval" =~ $hostNumberRE ]] ; then
            hostNumber="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
            if [[ "$linkval" =~ $ataNumberRE ]] ; then
                ataNumber="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
                scsiDevLetters[$scsiDevLetter]=`printf 'ata%-2.2s  host%-2.2s' "${ataNumber}" "${hostNumber}"`
                hostNumbers[${hostNumber}]=`printf '/dev/sd%s  ata%-2.2s' "${scsiDevLetter}" "${ataNumber}"`
                ataNumbers[${ataNumber}]=`printf '/dev/sd%s  host%-2.2s' "${scsiDevLetter}" "${hostNumber}"`
            elif [[ "$linkval" =~ $usbNumberRE ]] ; then
                usbNumber="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
                scsiDevLetters[$scsiDevLetter]=`printf 'usb%-2.2s  host%-2.2s' "${usbNumber}" "${hostNumber}"`
                hostNumbers[${hostNumber}]=`printf '/dev/sd%s  usb%-2.2s' "${scsiDevLetter}" "${usbNumber}"`

                existingUsbValue="${usbNumbers[${usbNumber}]}"
                addedUsbValue=`printf '/dev/sd%s  host%-2.2s' "${scsiDevLetter}" "${hostNumber}"`
                if [ -n "$existingUsbValue" ] ; then
                    usbNumbers[${usbNumber}]="$existingUsbValue | $addedUsbValue"
                else
                    usbNumbers[${usbNumber}]="$addedUsbValue"
        fi
            else
        echo "Neither ata nor usb: /dev/sd${scsiDevLetter} (host${hostNumber}) !"
            fi
        else
        echo "No host number for /dev/sd${scsiDevLetter}"
        fi
    fi
done    

echo '/dev/sd?'
echo '--------'
for scsiDevLetter in `echo "${!scsiDevLetters[*]}" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort` ; do
    echo "/dev/sd${scsiDevLetter}    ${scsiDevLetters[$scsiDevLetter]}"
done
echo
echo 'ataNN'
echo '-----'
for ataNumber in `echo "${!ataNumbers[*]}" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -n` ; do
    printf 'ata%-2.2s    %s\n' "$ataNumber" "${ataNumbers[$ataNumber]}"
done
echo
echo 'usbNN'
echo '-----'
for usbNumber in `echo "${!usbNumbers[*]}" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -n` ; do
    printf 'usb%-2.2s    %s\n' "$usbNumber" "${usbNumbers[$usbNumber]}"
done
echo
echo 'hostNN'
echo '------'
for hostNumber in `echo "${!hostNumbers[*]}" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -n` ; do
    printf 'host%-2.2s    %s\n' "$hostNumber" "${hostNumbers[$hostNumber]}"
done
```